# Trying to put Blog Title below Featured image on quark

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have been trying to put the blog title below the blog post on my customised quark theme. However, everytime I do I get a blank blog post page (except header)

The code is:

```
<header class="entry-header">
            <?php if ( is_single() ) { ?>
                <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <?php }
            else { ?>
                <h1 class="entry-title">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( esc_html__( 'Permalink to ', 'quark' ) . '%s', the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </h1>
            <?php } // is_single() ?>
            <?php quark_posted_on(); ?>
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && !is_search() ) { ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( esc_html__( 'Permalink to ', 'quark' ) . '%s', the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'post_feature_full_width' ); ?>
                </a>
            <?php } ?>
```

I change it to:

```
<header class="entry-header">
                    <?php } // is_single() ?>
            <?php quark_posted_on(); ?>
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && !is_search() ) { ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( esc_html__( 'Permalink to ', 'quark' ) . '%s', the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'post_feature_full_width' ); ?>
                </a>

    <?php if ( is_single() ) { ?>
                <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <?php }
            else { ?>
                <h1 class="entry-title">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( esc_html__( 'Permalink to ', 'quark' ) . '%s', the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </h1>

            <?php } ?>
```

I have also tried several variations of this with little success. I am sure I am being stupid, but any help would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following (based on my first answer and comments above):

```
<header class="entry-header">
        <?php quark_posted_on(); ?>
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && !is_search() ) { ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( esc_html__( 'Permalink to ', 'quark' ) . '%s', the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'post_feature_full_width' ); ?>
            </a>
        <?php } ?>
<?php if ( is_single() ) { ?>
            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php }
        else { ?>
            <h1 class="entry-title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( esc_html__( 'Permalink to ', 'quark' ) . '%s', the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </h1>

        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you man! Was massively frustrating me.

Comment: Great, happy to have helped! As mentioned in my other answers below the issue was due to the absence of corresponding tags in certain places (i.e. either closing or opening tags were missing). A potential way to quickly identify this is to take out all non PHP code and see if all is ok in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The second line may be causing issues unless there is a corresponding { somewhere above?

Comment: Similarly, is there a closing } somewhere for the { in the fourth line of your code?